# Is Rebol-based Cheyenne server able to process HTTP REST requests?

Tags: rest, http, webserver, rebol, cheyenne

Is Rebol-based Cheyenne server able to process HTTP REST requests like « /product/1234»  /   « /product/{productId}»  (with data in the URL, not as GET  parameters) ? It could be possible if Cheyenne can redirect URLs with wildcards like '/product*' or
'/product/*' to a single RSP (Rebol Server Page).

Is it possible through configuration ? 
I've tried a few different configurations (http.cfg) without success.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward way is to pass 404 error handling to some type of dispatcher, e.g. CGI or RSP:

```
default [
    default [%index.html]
    on-status-code [
        404 "/cgi-bin/request-handler.r"
    ]
]
```

My implementation of the [Rebol Desktop Project](http://desktop.rebol.info) has such an [`http.cfg`](https://github.com/revault/desktop.rebol.info/blob/master/cheyenne/httpd.cfg#L25).

Comment: Thank you very much for this 404 trick ! Very helpful. The drawback : no more default 404 behavior by configuration on the same virtual host, for other webapps running on the same Cheyenne server.